# Javascript not doing it's job

Tags: javascript, html

As you may know, I'm very new to HTML and JS.
I tried to make an image move when you click on it, but for a some reason it doesn't work. Can someone take a look at it?

(It's my first day of learning Javascript! Please keep this in mind)

Javascript

```
    var main = function() {
      $('document.Image').click(function() {
        $(this).animate({
          left: "100px"
        }, 200);
    });

};
```

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
<title>JS Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<img height="25px" width="25px" src="https://webdesignfromscratch.com/snippets/html-css-javascript.gif">
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: We will... Where is your code ?

Comment: Sorry for not adding the code! Forgot to add the code. 
Added code now...

Comment: I think there must be some more code, most probably you missed to include jQuery in your html page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You need to invoke/call `main` function
- `documemt.Image` was invalid selector. Give class as `.image` to element which can be selected using `$('.image')`
- To apply `left` css property in `.animate()`, element must be `absolute/relative/fixed` positioned. Review the updated `css`

```js
var main = function() {
  $('.image').click(function() {
    $(this).animate({
      left: "100px"
    }, 200);
  });
};
main();
```

```css
.image {
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class='image' height="25px" width="25px" src="https://webdesignfromscratch.com/snippets/html-css-javascript.gif">
```

Comment: Thank you but it still doesn't work for me....
I have no clue what I should do different...

Comment: NVM, got it working! Many thanks! One question, why is the following line required?
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

there is multiple mistake in your code... here is the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('img').click(function(){
$(this).animate({'margin-left': "300px"})
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<img style='margin-left:100px' src='' alt='no image' />
</body>
</html>
```

i m sure it helps u...